# Glassfish and javax.naming.NameNotFoundException after app Reload

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

**Environment:**

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1

disable-nonportable-jndi-names: true

**The problem:**

When I Deploy or Redeploy my application - everything works ok.
But after Reload or Disable/Enable following exception arises during connection from a standalone client:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/SynisBackendEAR/SynisBackend/UnitronicsDriver'...
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UnitronicsDriver not found...
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=com.protechnologia.synis.drivers.unitronics.UnitronicsDriver/configurationProvider,Local 3.x interface =com.protechnologia.synis.settings.ConfigurationProvider,ejb-link=null,lookup=java:app/SynisBackend/ConfigurationProviderXML,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class com.protechnologia.synis.drivers.unitronics.UnitronicsDriver: **object is not an instance of declaring class**
>
> ...

The code of a standalone client:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Driver bean = (Driver) ctx.lookup("java:global/SynisBackendEAR/SynisBackend/UnitronicsDriver");
bean.test();
```

I want to mention, that after Deployment or Redeployment everything works ok.

**The clue:**

I've found taht the problem is in following lookup taht is working on Deplyment and not working otherwise:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class UnitronicsDriver implements Driver {

    @EJB(lookup = "java:app/SynisBackend/ConfigurationProviderXML")
    protected ConfigurationProvider conf;
```

**Next clue:**

Replacing @EJB with manual lookup solves the problem but why?

```
conf = (ConfigurationProvider) ctx.lookup("java:app/SynisBackend/ConfigurationProviderXML");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally - found it!!!

The problem was, that the EJB I wanted to inject something in was implementing **@Remote** interface instead of **@Local**.

It has probably something to do wit pass-by-reference issue with @Remote interdaces.